# How can I find the index position of the center of a nxn

Tags: math, matrix

I would like to get the index of the center position of matrix. Is there any expression that can do this?

[image]

Comment: Try index = n/2?

Comment: Thank you, a friend of mine told me that i can do index=(nxn+1)/2.and works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `n` is odd, you can find the specified position by `mat[n/2][n/2]`. Now, to find the row index of the position by `f(n) = n * (n - 1) / 2 + (n + 1) / 2 = n^2 / 2 - n/2 + n/2 + 1/2 = (n^2 + 1)/2`.

For example, `f(3) = 3 * 1 + 2 = 5`, `f(5) = 5 * 2 + 3 = 13`, and `f(7) = 7 * 3 + 4 = 25`.

Comment: Thank you, a friend of mine told me that i can do index=(nxn+1)/2.and works!.